# Why is my print command executed twice in this Makefile?

Tags: makefile, include

For the record, I'm writing according to the next revision of the Single Unix Specification, which is Issue 8, and the `make` command is expected to have [some](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1325) new changes incorporated.

My make file is as follow:

```
.PHONY: all clean inc_phony

all: main.c
    ${CC} -o main -D LIB_RET=1${lib_ret} main.c

clean:
    rm -f inc main

inc: inc_phony
    printf 'lib_ret='`date +%S` > inc

include inc
```

The goal is that, whenever I type `make`, it remakes the `main` executable by inserting the second component of the current timestamp as a makefile variable into an include file, which is then specified as macro definition on the compilation commandline. I'm doing this so as to make myself familiar with the new workflow.

A phenomenon that I don't understand is that, the command associated with the `inc` target is executed twice (or at least, it's displayed twice on my terminal):

```
Prompt$ make
Makefile:12: inc: No such file or directory
printf 'lib_ret='`date +%S` > inc
printf 'lib_ret='`date +%S` > inc
cc -o main -D LIB_RET=127 main.c
```

And I'd like to ask the community what is causing this?

I think it may have something to do with the fact I specified `inc` both in the `include` directive and having a prerequisite that is a phony target. I'm not sure how to achieve the effect that `inc` be re-made exactly once everytime `make` is invoked.

The operating system I'm using is macOS Ventura 13.1, toolchain Xcode 14.2.

The content of `main.c` is as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){ return LIB_RET; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see it twice for these reasons:

The first time you see it is because the file doesn't exist, and GNU make will try to [remake include files](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html) that don't exist.  So you see this:

```
Makefile:12: inc: No such file or directory
printf 'lib_ret='`date +%S` > inc
```

Once that is done, make will re-exec itself so it can start over and read that makefile.  The second time make runs, the `inc` file exists so it can be read directly.  However, this rule:

```
inc: inc_phony
```

says that `inc` depends on a target `inc_phony` which is declared to be phony so it's ALWAYS considered out of date... that means that `inc`, which depends on it, must always be considered out of date as well, which means make will run that rule to build `inc` again.

I'm a bit surprised that this doesn't cause GNU make to re-exec itself again, basically forever.  My suspicion is that the Mac system you're using doesn't have a filesystem with sufficiently fine-grained modification times to recognize when the file has changed.  Or maybe you're using one of the bastardized versions of very old GNU make that Apple prefers to ship with their tools.

Comment: I'm working on an ExFAT portable SSD (so that I can work in Win, Mac, and any OS with `exfat-fuse`), that' explains the time resolusion.

Comment: I think exFAT has a mod time granularity of 10ms.  FAT had a granularity of 2s (!)

Answer (score 1):

This statement concerning what targets can be considered up-to-date is in the draft:

> ..., except that targets that are made up-to-date in order for them to be processed as include line pathnames (see **Include Lines** below) need not be considered up-to-date during later processing. ...

Bolds are that from the draft, I've made no modification to the quoted text other than trimming to the parts that're the most relevant.